# Accessing object's attributes in Multiple ArrayList in java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, vector

I have written only necessary information to make you understand the error.
I have a multiple arraylist(specification) i.e.

```
speci={{node,node},{node,node}}
```

The node is an object that contains an int and a boolean i.e.

```
node= int value , boolean explored
```

I wanted  to access the int of the node object through following way,

```
System.out.println(speci.get(0).get(0).value); // IDE is not accepting it, suggest a way
```

My IDE(NetBeans8.1) is not accepting, saying cannot find symbol value. How can I access that value using ArrayList? TIA :-)

Answer (score 0):

Within your `node` class define `getter` for the fields and then use -

```
System.out.println(speci.get(0).get(0).getValue());
```

Under an assumption, that `speci` is somewhat -

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<node>> speci;
```

and `node`(would suggest renaming this to `Node` instead) would be like -

```
public class Node {
    int value;
    ... // other attributes
    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    ...// other getters and setters
}
```

Here is a useful link on [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Your answer does not explain why the OP is getting the error.

Comment: @k132322AftabHussain There is an assumption I wrote. Please share your complete code in the question itself to look further into things.